# Creating a Shell Script that deletes specified files in git repo

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, git

How would I create a script that would take a list of file names in a git repository (I was planning on using a .txt file with one file name on each line, but I am open to other suggestions) as an input, and then remove those specified files from the repository?

I was thinking about using the 'cat' command and a pipe, so that in the terminal the commands would look something like this:

```
cd my-git-repo
cat fileNames.txt | myShellScript.sh
git push origin master
```

And then 'myShellScript.sh' would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
git rm $0
git add .
git commit -m "removed unused file"
```

Also I know there should be some type of 'read' command to read fileNames.txt line by line.

Comment: Have you attempted anything so far?  This question as written is probably too broad.  Your question would be much better received if you attempted to write it (even if it's a poor attempt) and then asked question(s) here about any specific problem(s) you encounter.  I definitely recommend creating a test repository to work with though in order to avoid unintentionally deleting the wrong data.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your code from a git repo with `rsync`. A file e.g. `exclude-rsync.txt` could contain all files and directories (one per line) you don't want to deploy to the target (could be a new directory, too).

**exlude-rsync.txt**

```
.git
.gitignore
include/database.yml
```

**rsync command**

```
 rsync -avz --delete --exclude-from=exclude-rsync.txt . foo@192.168.0.123:/var/www/foobar/
```

**CI / CD pipelines**

With gitlab, travis ci (& jenkins) you can define ci/cd piplines usually in a yaml file. Whenever something is pushed to git(lab) or a branch is merged to master, the pipeline will start automatically. For gitlab you would add a file called `.gitlab-ci.yml` and it could look like this:

```
stages:
  - deploy
deploy_production:
  stage: deploy
  environment: production
  only:
    - master@my_repo
  before_script:
    - yum -y install rsync    
  script:
    - |
       rsync -avz --delete --exclude-from=exclude-rsync.txt . foo@192.168.0.123:/var/www/foobar/
```

But in a simpler case you would add a shell file e.g. `deploy.sh` having in mind that those pipelines exist and it might be good practice.

```
#!/bin/bash
rsync -avz --delete --exclude-from=exclude-rsync.txt . foo@192.168.0.123:/var/www/foobar/
```